# Redirect to specific view

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3

I want to redirect the user of my app to a specific view if he is logged in or not. This is my code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        }

        else {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        }
}
```

If I open my app I always get a white screen.
Does anyone know my mistake?

Comment: you need to 'wait' until your presenter has arrived into the navigation stack, than you can present another view from it.

Answer (score -1):

It worked. I didn't connected the navigation controller in the storyboard. The code itself works finde.